# Iniciante cmprei um notebook com Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, 23.10

Gostaria de voltar o notebook para configurações de fábrica que vinha com o ubunt 20.04. Atualizei sem querer para o 23.10. Como faço essa restauração para a consfiguraçõs de fábrica? Alguém pode me ajudar? Totalmente iniciante querendo aprender. Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Please translate your question in english.

Comment: I would like to return the notebook to the factory settings that came with Ubuntu 20.04. I accidentally updated to 23.10. How do I restore this to factory settings? Can someone help me? Totally beginner wanting to learn. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1506862/edit) and change it to English. Also add more information about how you upgraded from 20.04 to 23.10, as there is no direct upgrade path. Also include more details about the notebook make and model. Factory reset options if any would be implemented by the notebook's manufacturer. You will have to contact the company. Otherwise you can install a current version of Ubuntu (20.04, 22.04, or 23.10) from an installation USB.